# Div, image and text height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

I'm having a little problem with the size of my DIV.
I need to create a div that has a square image on the left, and text on the right. The main problem is that this is a responsive website, and I can't know the final size of anything... I need the width and the height of the image to be the same height of the text (the Div is the container), and they need to change automatically...
I was trying, but it doesn't work:

HTML

```
<div id="barra">
    <div id="logosw">
        <img src="images/awa.png" alt="awa"/>
    </div>
    <div id="textsw">
        <p class="teli">Bala emerged on the market, with the goal of offering high quality services, for a competitive price. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#barra{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logosw img{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

#textsw{
    float: right;
    width: 76%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}
```

I need something like this:

```
#barra{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logosw img{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4%;
    width: auto;
    height: same as #textsw;
}

#textsw{
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - #logosw);
    height: 100% of the text;
}
```

This way the image would change it size, but it would be exactly the same as the text heigh... The combination would be always 100% of the page width, with the image and the text always the same height... Thanks

Comment: What if the text is only 16px tall...should the image also be the same height? This seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no CSS layout that would do this...not even flexbox. I suspect you need JS.

Comment: You can use javascript `elem.offsetHeight` and link it to a `resize` event of the browser window.

Comment: @Paulie_D if the text is 16ox tall, the image would be 16px X 16px... It's an odd requirement... I know, but I need it to work :-/ The text would never be that small...

Comment: If you get a lot of text then chances are you image might even outscale the viewport. You'll almost certainly need JS for this.